# SQLITE Operators "=" compare with "< AND >" performance difference

Tags: performance, sqlite, operators

I've got a strange problem with my sql queries' performance. When I use operator **=** in *LEFT JOIN* query takes about 30.514 minutes seconds but in a case with **< AND >** it takes only 1.717 seconds. This is the query:

```
-- data_filehash.size>4095 AND data_filehash.size<4097  || 1.717 seconds
SELECT files.*, data_filehash.* 
FROM v_filesp AS files 
LEFT JOIN data_filehash ON files.id = data_filehash.file AND data_filehash.size>4095 AND data_filehash.size<4097  
WHERE data_filehash.file IS NULL

-- data_filehash.size=4096 || 30.515 minutes
SELECT files.*, data_filehash.* 
FROM v_filesp AS files
LEFT JOIN data_filehash ON files.id = data_filehash.file AND data_filehash.size=4096  
WHERE data_filehash.file IS NULL
```

Results are always same (33016 records in my database);
*v_filep* is a view; I've got indexes on data_filehash.size, data_filehash.file and primary key on files(v_filesp).id;

I think that isn't normal. Maybe I should configure something or I don't understand that.

There are EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for both queries:

query wih **=** (slower)

```
SEARCH TABLE files USING INDEX files_c_dup (c_dup=?)
SEARCH TABLE dirs USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
SEARCH TABLE data_filehash USING INDEX index_size (size=?)
```

query with **< AND >** (faster)

```
SEARCH TABLE files USING INDEX files_c_dup (c_dup=?)
SEARCH TABLE dirs USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
SEARCH TABLE data_filehash USING INDEX index_file (file=?)
```

Last steps are different but what does it mean? How can I tell the db that it should use second better algorithm in the first query?

Comment: Show the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for both queries.

Comment: can you post the schema for the table?  does size have an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update, at first I misread this to be that the inequality comparison was much slower. Which is usually what one expects. It wasn't the case, so let's have another crack at it.*

With the inequality comparision The engine first has to find all the records that match the condition size > 4095 it's quite likely that there will be very many. There may be so many matches that it would be futile for the engine to use an index. A full table scan could happen.

*But sqlite can only use one index per table in a query. If it cannot use an index on size the best thing is to use the index on file. And this null comparison probably eliminates a large number of rows which leads to a faster query.*

It's much simpler with an equality comparison so it looks to use the index on the size field *but this probably eliminates a much smaller number of rows than with the other index on is null.*

If this still doesn't explain matters, can you update your question to show the number of records returned, the number of records with *file=4096* and number of null `names`.

Comment: If I correctly understood you, query with **=** should be faster - it's logic; But in my case it is slower 30*60 times. Why?

Comment: had another crack at it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it works corectly with equality comparison. I added **INDEXED BY**:

```
SELECT files.*, data_filehash.* 
FROM v_filesp AS files 
LEFT JOIN data_filehash INDEXED BY index_file
ON files.id = data_filehash.file AND data_filehash.size=4096
WHERE files.c_dup=1 AND data_filehash.file IS NULL
```

Thanks e4c5